# How can I get information from image when I click the image by onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm making sliding puzzle using JavaScript.I used 'name' to hold the image files as an array.
And I give 'onClick' to an image files to know any image's that is clicked information about order of image files in the array. But it is not worked. How can I get the information when image is clicked.

```
<body bgcolor="silver" text="black" link="#0000EE" vlink="#551A8B" alink="red">
<h2 align="center">
15 puzzle</h2>
<div align="center">
<table border>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="center">

    <script language="JavaScript">
    with(window.document){
        open();
        writeln('<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1>');
        for(var i=1;i<17;i++){
        if(i==1||i==5||i==9||i==13)
            writeln('<tr>');
        writeln('   <td width=49 height=49>');
        writeln('   <a href=JavaScript:void(0);>');
        **writeln(' <img src=',i,'.gif border=0 width=49 height=49 name=i',i,' onClick="movePiece(i)"></a>');**
        writeln('   </td>');
        if(i==4||i==8||i==12||i==16)
            writeln('</tr>');
        }
        writeln('</table>');
        close();
    }
    </script>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<p align="center">
<br>
</p>
<form method="get">
<p align="center">
<input type="button" value="시작" onClick="shuffle()"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for `movePiece` function also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick="movePiece(i)" => onClick="movePiece(",i,")"

Answer (score 0):

you do not have a function called "movePiece(i)" in your javascript. you need to add this first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what data are you trying to get from the img but it seems like passing 'this' to your function will do the trick.

'this' simply means pass the element that the function is on. Then you can access all of the element's properties

If this is not what you meant, please make the question clearer

```html
<img src='' border=0 width=49 height=49 name="someName" onClick="movePiece(this)">
<script>
    function movePiece(elImg) {
        console.log(elImg.name) //someName
    }
</script>
```